# Get list of clients' IP addresses in an NIO.2 server

Tags: java, networking, asynchronous, synchronization, nio

In a server based on AsynchronousServerSocketChannel and AsynchronousSocketChannel, how can I check whether a connection from a given IP address already exists? I want to send a specific message to connections that come from an IP address that is already connected (asking it to try again later; I'm dealing with very specific client-side LANs whose bandwidth will be poorly utilized if shared rather than forced to serialize by the server). However, I see no way to get a list of IP addresses to search for whether the same IP address already has a connection. Is there a more elegant/efficient way to do this other than inserting the IP addresses of each new connection to (and removing them upon closing from) something like a ConcurrentSkipListSet?

Moreover, I want to periodically gather a few network statistics from all open connections (how many chunks of a file have been uploaded, say). The only way I came up with to do this efficiently is send updates from the completion handlers (of a chunk-sending network write) to the info gathering thread using ConcurrentLinkedQueue, waking the thread any time something is inserted into the queue. I'm assuming the wake operation is non-blocking but I don't know how expensive it may be, as I'm sure at the very least it involves an interlocked CPU instruction (which implies a memory fence and affects execution speed even further etc.). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to maintain your own data structures. All TCP will give you is the sockets, from which you can get their remote addresses and ports.